# Doctrine 2 Querybuilder - Two joins leads to wrong sum results

Tags: doctrine-orm

I need to generate reports, this work fine

```
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('
            c.category, 
            SUM(s.fulfillable)   AS fulfillable
        ')
        ->from('App\Entity\Catalog', 'c')
        ->leftJoin('App\Entity\Stock', 's', Expr\Join::WITH, 'c.sku = s.sku')
        ->groupBy('c.category')
    ;
```

but when I also want to sum transaction results (multiple), my fulfillable sum is not true anymore

```
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('
            c.category, 
            SUM(s.fulfillable) AS fulfillable,
            SUM(t.sold)        AS sold  
        ')
        ->from('App\Entity\Catalog', 'c')
        ->leftJoin('App\Entity\Stock', 's', Expr\Join::WITH, 'c.sku = s.sku')  // Only one Stock
        ->leftJoin('App\Entity\Transaction', 't', Expr\Join::WITH, 'c.sku = t.sku') // Multiple Transactions
        ->groupBy('c.category')
    ;
```

Is there a solution for such cases in Doctrine ORM? Or do I have to use raw sql querys with subselects.

Thank you & Best Regards

Comment: Did you have the raw SQL query? Have you run this query in a tool and check whether the problem is Doctrine or not? I do not think the problem is Doctrine but your SQL but I might be wrong

Comment: Hi. The problem is, with two "group by", subqueries are needed for every group by and doctrine do not support joins on subqueries. So running raw sql queries with doctrine is the only solution as far as i know.